# Installing geminabox Gem with mod_passenger - 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, passenger

i'm trying to install the geminabox application on my server using mod_passenger. But for some reason it's always giving me a 'Service Temporarily Unavailable' and i don't know where to look. I've checked the apache error_log and also put the LogLevel to debug, but i can't find any reason why it's giving me the 'Service Unavailable' message. I have also set the debug level of passenger to level 3 but can't find nothing there. When i go to the /upload url of the application i get the page, but uploading fails. Any idea how i can debug this a bit further? Of even better what's wrong.

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 with passenger 3.0.2 and this is my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost <my_ip>:80>
    ServerName geminabox.uranus.kunstmaan.be 
    ServerAdmin support@kunstmaan.be 
    DocumentRoot <path_to_the_project>/data/public

    ServerAlias geminabox.uranus.kunstmaan.be www.geminabox.uranus.kunstmaan.be

    <Directory <path_to_the_project>/data/public >
        Options -Indexes MultiViews Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog <path_to_the_project>/apachelogs/error.log
    CustomLog <path_to_the_project>/apachelogs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My passenger log stays empty, in the error log of apache i'm getting this:

```
[Fri Dec 16 17:53:50 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 172.18.19.222] Zlib: Compressed 526 to 357 : URL /
```

If any more information is required please let me know.

kind regards,

Daan